# Помогите понять почему SequenceInputStream неработает

Tags: java, input, filestream

Программа принимает два аргумента:
`C:\test0.zip C:\test.zip`

в каждом из архивов есть простые .txt файлы.

> Output:
> Current Entry is: testFile1.txt  and the size is: 16
> Current Entry is: testFile2.txt  and the size is: 16

только первый архив :(

Почему `SequenceInputStream` работает только с первым архивом?

В документации написано:

> A SequenceInputStream represents the logical concatenation of other input streams. It starts out with an ordered collection of input streams and reads from the first one until end of file is reached, whereupon it reads from the second one, and so on, until end of file is reached on the last of the contained input streams.

если я правильно понимаю он должен работать с разными `InputStream`-ами или это не так?

заранее благодарю!

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<FileInputStream> fileInputStreamArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        fileInputStreamArrayList.add(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
        fileInputStreamArrayList.add(new FileInputStream(args[1]));

        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(fileInputStreamArrayList)));

        ZipEntry zipEntry;
        String fileName;
        long fileSize;

        while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry())!=null) {

            fileName = zipEntry.getName();
            fileSize = zipEntry.getSize();

            System.out.printf("Current Entry is: "+fileName + "\t and the size is: " + fileSize + "\n");

            zipInputStream.closeEntry();

        }



    }
```

Comment: Может дело в том, что вы идёте по zipEntry а не по SequenceInputStream ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что `ZipInputStream` предназначен строго для чтения 1 (одного) zip архива. Не двух, не трех, а только **одного**, а вы пытаетесь его обмануть подсунув ему поток из 2-х файлов, но как видно номер не прокатывает...

По идее, если вы хотите поток из 2-х файлов превратить в 1 поток, вам надо наоборот:

1. Создать 2 потока `ZipInputStream`: `zipStream1`, `zipStream2`
2. Далее упаковать оба этих потока в `new SequenceInputStream(zipStream1, zipStream2)`